# Accesing specific properties and iterating over JSON array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

So, I'm new to angular and it's syntax, but here is my problem, 2 to be more specific. 
I have this data in .JSON file and I want to access a specific element in that array from my controller. I dont want to use ng-repeat, I just want to loop through or access an element in controller. 
So this is clearly not possible:

```
app.controller('drinkController', function($scope, drinkFactory){

   $scope.data;

   drinkFactory.getData().success(function(data){
       $scope.data = data;
   });

   $scope.specific = $scope.data[0].level;


});
```

Here is JSON file:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "level": 1,
    "task": "Task1",
    "kapacitet": 10,
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "level": 2,
    "task": "Task2",
    "kapacitet": 10,
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "level": 2,
    "task": "Task3",
    "kapacitet": 10,
},

]
```

2. Is it possible to do a specific search like, loop through all elements where "level" = 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do a specific search like, loop through all elements
>   where "level" = 2?

try

Assuming that `$scope.data` is the array you want to iterate.

It needs to be inside the success method

```
drinkFactory.getData().success(function(data){
       $scope.data = data;
       var filteredItems = $scope.data.filter(function(value){return value.level == 2});
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I get this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. I can't figure out how is the $scope.data undefined, it works when I acces it from html.

Comment: @ogee it needs to be inside success method, check my code

Comment: is it possible to do a specific search in pure javascript?

Comment: @Ognjen what I have given is pure JavaScript. Only thing I have taken from your code is `$scope.data`.  Replace this with any array, it should work without adding any library.